# Syntax error in "insert into statement" on MS-Access using Delphi6

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

When i execute SQL Query directly on MS-Access it will insert the Record, but when via TADOQuery component in Delphi, show above error. What is Error in my Code?

Here is my Code:

```
strQuery := 'INSERT INTO MAS_User_Master
            (First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, User_Name, Password, Mobile_No, 
             Email_Id, Security_Question, Security_Answer, Is_Admin, Is_Deleted,
             Created_By, Created_Date) 
            VALUES
            ('Adam', 'G.', 'James', 'adam', 'ada23',9999599990,
             'adam@yahoo.com', 'what', 'yes', -1, 0,
             'admin', Now())'

qryExec.SQL.Add(strQuery);
qryExec.ExecSQL();
```

EDIT:

Above strQuery value is copied at Run-Time. To Create statement i used below Code:

```
strQuery := 'INSERT INTO MAS_User_Master ' +
                  '(First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, User_Name, Password, Mobile_No, Email_Id, '+
                  'Security_Question, Security_Answer, Is_Admin, Is_Deleted, Created_By, Created_Date) '+
                  'VALUES (''' + UserRec.FirstName + ''', ''' + UserRec.MiddleName +
                  ''', ''' + UserRec.LastName + ''', ''' +  UserRec.UserName + ''', ''' + UserRec.Password +
                  ''',' + UserRec.MobileNubmer + ', ''' + UserRec.EmailId + ''', '+
                  '''' + UserRec.SecurityQuestion + ''', ''' + UserRec.SecurityAnswer + ''', ' +
                  UserRec.IsAdmin + ', 0, '''+ g_strUserName + ''', Now())';
```

Comment: Even in access, line breaks are allowed. :)

Comment: Use double quotes around string values or double the quotes around them in the SQL text. It's not just MarkDown's syntax highlighter that is showing you what's wrong.

Comment: although it's more typing I would recommend the usage of parameters to get rid of triplequoting, problems with datefomats etc.

Comment: @Marjan would double quotes be allowed there by ADO and  Access ? in SQL they are used to separate non-trivial column and table names like in `select "super Column" from "немножко exotic table" where...`

Comment: @Arioch'The: Can't check now, but I think they are as I always needed to double up double quotes when writing VBA code (where a single quote is the start character for a line comment).

Comment: @Marjan By single quote you mean apostrophe ? sure, probably VBA has that quirk. But in Delphi you can include apostrophe into the string to double it, so double quote may be governed by different rules. OTOH given MS SQL habit to close column names into square brackets, perhaps they did not dare to treat double quotes by SQL standard.

Comment: @Arioch'The: that's why I said use double quotes, or double the quotes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thank You! All of You..
```

I found the Solution :

All of the Above Queries and Syntax are Correct and Working..

```
Important thing:
```

i have one ***Field*** Named '**PASSWORD**' in *MS-Access Database*. Delphi has reserved this word, so we can not use them. I changed name of the Field and All the stuff working fine...

Comment: Good find, but no cigar. :-) The problem is that it's a reserved word in Access SQL, not Delphi.

Comment: @GolezTrol Nop, it's reserved word of DELPHI, because when i copy SQL string and Paste directly in **MS-Access**, it is working fine with "**PASSWORD**" field name.

Comment: Maybe it's an ADO or driver issue, but it's not Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

```
qryExec.Paramcheck := true;
qryExec.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MAS_User_Master '
            +'(First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, User_Name, [Password], Mobile_No, '
            +' Email_Id, Security_Question, Security_Answer, Is_Admin, Is_Deleted,'
            +' Created_By, Created_Date)'
            +'VALUES'
            +'(:fn, :mn, :ln, :un, :pw,:mno,'
            +' :em, :q, :an, :isad, :isDel,'
            +' :cb, :cd)';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('fn').Value := 'Adam';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('mn').Value := 'G.';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('ln').Value := 'James';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('un').Value := 'adam';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('pw').Value := 'ada23';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('mno').Value := 9999599990;
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('em').Value := 'adam@yahoo.com';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('q').Value := 'what';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('an').Value := 'yes';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('isad').Value := -1;
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('isdel').Value := 0;
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('cb').Value := 'admin';
qryExec.Parameters.ParamByName('cd').Value := Now();
qryExec.ExecSQL();
```

another way could be:

```
AdoDataset.CommandText :='Select * from MAS_User_Master where 1=0';
AdoDataset.Append;
Adodataset.FieldByName('First_Name').Value := 'Adam';
// and so on
Adodataset.Post;
```

Comment: +1 for parameters (and i'll get a beer from you, fill up to 3500 rep ;o) )

Comment: i copied above Parametrized code, but still getting "SYNTAX ERROR in INSERT INTO Statement".

Comment: @Gani - did you already changed Sql.Add for `qryExec.SQL.Text := ` ? You've been prompted to fix it many times but you never yet told you did that.  Before calling `qryExec.ExecSQL();` add one more line: `ShowMessage(qryExec.SQL.Text);` and what u see there ?

Comment: Password is a reserved word ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738 ) and in MS Access sql it would either be prefixed with an alias or table name or enclosed in square brackets: `[Password]`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of could-be errors

First, your query contains quotes. To use a quote in a string in Delphi, you must type a double quote to escape it, otherwise it is seen as a string terminator. This will generate a Delphi compile error.

Second, you `Add` to the SQL. This means, if the SQL property already contains information, this statement is added to it, likely resulting in an invalid statement. This would generate a runtime error, generated by ADO at the time of executing the ExecSQL method.

Other things you can do, that won't solve your problem directly, but make your life easier and your project more maintainable:

Use the object inspector to edit the SQL property. You won't need to escape quotes, can easily add line breaks, and can execute the same query, as is, in Access to test. 
You can use a TADOQuery (or rather a TADOCommand for insert and update statement) per statement you need to execute, so you never have to update the SQL itself.

To use 'variable values' in the statements, you can use the *Parameters* of the command.

To make sure they are not in the way, blocking the site of your form when designing, you can put the commands on a data module.

Comment: would you put his modified sources (modified to use params) into the answer ?

Comment: I could, but I didn have time this morning. Also, I feel that pointing someone to the right direction doesn't need an example per se. If they get stuck trying out parameters, they can always ask a new question. :)

Comment: Many times i feel the same, but this almost inevitably leads to someone implementing my hints and stealing my thunder ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The  I had to look up that expression and am still not sure what you mean. Is it about bummi gaining the points for adding a fully working snippet of code? That happens to me a lot, because I rather give hints and make people think than to provider a ready to use example without context. If that costs me points, then I can live with that.

Comment: There was no idioms (only if for mere coincidence), and yes, i meant exactly that (and often act the same ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you should use double quotas to insert one quote into string.
Make sure `qryExec.SQL` is empty. Just do `qryExec.SQL.Clear` before `qryExec.SQL.Add`. 
Also `Now()` is a Delphi function so you should convert results of `Now()` into string to put it into SQL query.

```
strQuery := 'INSERT INTO MAS_User_Master (First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, User_Name, Password, Mobile_No, Email_Id, Security_Question, Security_Answer, Is_Admin, Is_Deleted, Created_By, Created_Date) VALUES (''Adam'', ''G.'', ''James'', ''adam'', ''ada23'',9999599990, ''adam@yahoo.com'', ''what'', ''yes'', -1, 0, ''admin'', '''+DateToStr(Now())+''' )';

qryExec.SQL.Add(strQuery);
qryExec.ExecSQL();
```

Comment: now i used 'Clear' Method for SQL and then 'Add' method, but still have same problem.

Comment: Did you use strQuery string from my answer?

Comment: i also used Now() in another Query and it stores DateTime as a MS-Access Function. i have passed 'now()' without quotes.

Comment: i also tried Your Above Code for NOW() function, but still have problem.